A certain proof method for Ky Fan's sphere covering theorem
Ky Fan's theorem (1952) for sphere covering states the following:

Let $A_1, A_2,\dots,A_m$ be an antipodal-free (which means $A_i\cap (-A_i)=\varnothing$) closed (can be open, let's go with closed for now) cover of the sphere $S^d$. Then there exists indices $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_{d+2}$ such that $\bigcap_{j=1}^{d+2}(-1)^jA_{i_j}\ne\varnothing$.

While trying to prove this, I have stumbled upon a proof (see here for example) of a similar result (which is reminiscent of the Lyusternik and Shnirel’man theorem), but I can't extend the proof idea to prove the above theorem. What I can show is the following:

Let $A_1, A_2,\dots,A_{d+1}$ be an antipodal-free collection of sets such that $S^d=\bigcup_i(A_i\cup(-A_i))$. Then $\bigcap_i s_iA_i\ne\varnothing$ for any choice of signs $s_i$.

The proof is essentially by assuming a small enough centrally symmetric triangulation $T_\varepsilon$ of $S^d$ for some small enough $\varepsilon$ (which can be taken to be the minimum distance between a set in the cover and it's antipodal counterpart) to make the faces have diameter less than $\varepsilon$. Then we label the vertices with labels from $[d+1]\cup(-[d+1])$ so that it forms an antipodal labelling.
Now we fix some signs. Then we note that there is some edge with labels summing to non-zero, and hence must have a face with labels as $s_i\cdot i$ (see theorem 3.1 in the linked paper). By looking at it's barycenter and letting $\varepsilon\to 0$, we get our result.

The issue is that this proof gives $d+1$ indices, 1 less than $d+2$. Also, the assumption of the cover is slightly different than in Ky Fan's theorem. My question is, can we give a proof for Ky Fab's theorem using this proof approach? Specifically using triangulations and some modification of theorem 3.1?
Any help is much appreciated!
